# How do I translate a meta-package (.deb)?

Tags: 11.10, deb, translation

I have created a meta-package called communtu-add-sources-lewisgoddard-liberta-bundle_2_i386.deb on en.commutu.org

Unfortunately the packages installer language (it has a popup window when adding sources) is in German. How do i go about translating it?

[Download](http://cloud.eustasy.co.uk/apps/files_sharing/get.php?token=fac7554d83ac62cc24312e99994260ee33da67e9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your preinst

Find and replace "Paketquellen hinzufügen" with "add repositories"
Find and replace "Folgende Paketquellen und Schlüssel werden hinzugefügt" with "the following repositories and software keys will be added"
Find and replace "Schlüssel" with "software keys"

Answer (score 1):

Start here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Translations